# Audio recording with OpenAL on android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, audio-recording, openal

I have some problem with using of recording audio on android. I've experience of OpenAL on iOS, but that not helping me. I tried many examples, but I always get the same problem:

alcCaptureOpenDevice( NULL, SRATE, FORMAT, SSIZE ) returns null

I've android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO in AndroidManifest.xml.

P.S. I use my С++ code which works on iOS. Playback and more from OpenAL is working correctly on android. I've problem just with capture.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find answer for my question. So I had to use OpenSL ES specially for native recording on android. So an usual and streaming recordings are working fine.